# How can i scroll to specific row in QTableView?

Tags: python, scroll, pyqt5, qtableview, scrollto

I want to scroll a spesific row in my table. My QTableView Model code is below.

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self,name,number,status):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.status = status

class CustomerTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    ROW_BATCH_COUNT = 1000

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomerTableModel,self).__init__()
        self.headers = ['             İsim             ','  Telefon No (Örn 9053xx..)  ','   Mesaj Durumu   ']
        self.customers  = []
        self.rowsLoaded = CustomerTableModel.ROW_BATCH_COUNT

    def rowCount(self,index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not self.customers:
            return 0

        if len(self.customers) <= self.rowsLoaded:
            return len(self.customers)
        else:
            return self.rowsLoaded

    def addCustomer(self,customer):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.customers.append(customer)
        self.endResetModel()

    def columnCount(self,index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.headers)

    def data(self,index,role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        col = index.column()
        customer = self.customers[index.row()]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if col == 0:
                return QtCore.QVariant(customer.name)
            elif col == 1:
                return QtCore.QVariant(customer.number)
            elif col == 2:
                return QtCore.QVariant(customer.status)
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter

    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return QtCore.QVariant(self.headers[section])
        return QtCore.QVariant(int(section + 1))
```

I found a function for this problem but it works on QTableWidget. That I found code is below.

```
self.QtTableWidget.scrollToItem(item)
```

I can't use this function for QTableView. How can i do it? Any other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for all the classes that inherit from QAbstractItemView(like QTableView, QTableWidget, QListView, etc) there is the [`scrollTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo) method that is used internally to [`scrollToItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#scrollToItem):

```
row = 4
column = 0
index = table_view.model().index(row, column)
table_view.scrollTo(index)
```